# Verificar todas as requisições

Tags: javascript, node.js

Olá, 
Estou usando o express-session e gostaria de saber como verificar a sessão de todas as requisições que chegam no server. 
Por exemplo, hoje eu estou usando o trecho em todas as minhas rotas:

```
app.get('/telemetrias', (req, res) => {
    if (!req.session.uniqueId) {
        res.redirect('/');
        return;
    }
});
```

Ou seja, em cada rota tem esse IF para verificar a sessão. E gostaria que o nodejs verificasse cada requisição antes de direciona-la para a rota específica.

Não existe a tag express-session e também não tenho pontuação para criar tags.

Answer (score 1):

Basta criar um middleware e atribuí-la na função `app.use`:

```
const validar = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.session.uniqueId) {
    res.redirect('/');
    return;
  }

  next();
};

app.use(validar);
```

Comment: pois é.. eu já tentei fazer isso, mas nao funciona. 
Para que a aplicação entra num looping. E na verdade faz sentido que entre, pois não existe sessão, dai direciona para a rota "/", dai quando direciona ele entre novamente nesse middleware e direciona novamente para a rota "/".

Comment: Esse projeto está no github: 
https://github.com/diegocacilha/EstacaoMeteorologica

Este projeto usa o boby-parser, express, express-session, consign, helmet.

Comment: Ok. Até funciona. Mas tem um problema, quando o usuário tenta logar, a sessão ainda não existe e entra de novo nesse middleware e o usuário nao consegue logar

Comment: @DiegoArmandoCacilha ué, mas sua pergunta dizia "todas as requisições". Você pode se basear na resposta da pergunta [**Exclude route from express middleware**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27118077/3388148) para conseguir o que quer

Comment: ah tá.. OK! Esqueci de citar que a tentativa de login não precisa passar por esse middleware, pois é justamente essa requisição que cria a session

Comment: @DiegoArmandoCacilha aí você quer uma magia pra descobrir o que é e o que não é.